# Visualforce display list of records only goes half way across the form

Tags: apex, visualforce

Classic page layout.  I have an Apex controller that retrieves records.  I have a VF page that displays the data.  Great, it works and I dropped it on the form.  The problem:  it only displays on the left half of the form.  I guess that is because SFDC pages are essentially two halves.  This is a list of records and I would like it to display like a related list - all the way across the form.  Seems so stupid I can't figure this out.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"
           extensions="AP_ViewTaskrayProjForAcctPod_Controller">


        <apex:pageBlock>
            <table>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listTaskrayProjects}" var="vcc">
                    <apex:column headervalue="Taskray Project">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!vcc.Id}" target="_blank">{!vcc.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!vcc.TASKRAY__trAccount__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!vcc.Appointment__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!vcc.TASKRAY__Project_Start__c}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>

            </table>
        </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the apex:pageBlockTable inside a table.

```
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listTaskrayProjects}" var="vcc">
            <apex:column headervalue="Taskray Project">
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!vcc.Id}" target="_blank">{!vcc.Name}</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!vcc.TASKRAY__trAccount__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!vcc.Appointment__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!vcc.TASKRAY__Project_Start__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Thank you for that response.  You are likely right, I think that was an artifact of one of my million attempts to make it work.  But alas, taking out <table> doesn't change anything - it still spans only half the page.

Comment: @DeanWooldridge Hmm, I'd need to see the surrounding context. The block itself should take up the entire width at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, dang.  I dropped the VF page in a section defined as two columns on the page form.  Created a new one column section, moved puppy in there and bang - full width.  Geez...... call this one social isolation from my brain!